# Add 23 hrs 59 minutes as a unix time stamp in PHP

Tags: php, date, unix, time

Can someone give me a working example of what my code should be as my efforts are getting me nowhere?

My code currently says have

```
if (isset($_POST['startdate'])) {
    $startdate = DatePickerToTime($_POST['startdate']);
} else { 
    $startdate = strtotime('today midnight');
}
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['enddate'])) { 
    $enddate = DatePickerToTime($_POST['enddate']);
} else { 
    $enddate = time();
}
```

which works.

However, I want to say if `startdate` is equal to `enddate` then add 23 hours and 59 minutes to `enddate`

I have read the documentation and am trying

```
if($_POST['$startdate'] == $_POST['$enddate']) {
    $_POST['$enddate'] += date("h:i:sa", "23:59:59");
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: check the documentation again, the 2nd param of [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is an int, so passing `"23:59:59"` wouldn't work. Rather than adding 23hours, 59minutes and 59seconds, could you go down this route `strtotime('tomorrow midnight -1 second')`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$datetime1 = date('2009-10-11 12:30:00');
$datetime2 = date('2009-10-11 12:30:00');
echo "<pre>";
if($datetime1 == $datetime2){
    echo "yes";
    echo "<br>";
    $datetime2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+23 hours 59 minutes",strtotime($datetime2)));
    echo $datetime1."===================".$datetime2;
}
else {
    echo "NO<br>";
    echo $datetime1."===================".$datetime2;
}
```